# Which is the last Debian release to not support .deb?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, package-management, deb

Can someone tell me which Debian release (and Ubuntu release) is the last one to not support deb packages or first release to support deb packages. I am not even sure if there are any releases like that. But if there are. I need to know.

Comment: What makes you thing that it stopped?

Comment: I suppose Ubuntu is slowly moving towards `snappy`

Answer (score 2):

Both Debian and Ubuntu always used DEB packages. The only change I'm aware of happened in Debian 0.93 where the DEB package format changed see [deb-old manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/dpkg-dev/deb-old.5.en.html).